# Mac Audio framework

Tags: iphone, macos, audio

I know that AVFoundation framework works on iPhone.
Does the same framework be used for Mac as well to play and record sounds???
Basically I want to write an application to play 2 music files parallelly and record the music that is being played. Is it possible???

Answer (score 2):

No, AVFoundation is for the iPhone only.

What does work cross platform (iPhone, OS X) is the Audio Queue framework. It is more difficult to use but there are plenty of examples available. It is also more low level so it will allow you to do stuff like playing and recording.